React Router: ¿Por qué mi proyecto de React generado al ejecutar npm run build se queda en blanco?
Esto es algo que me ha dado problemas y no hay una respuesta directa y clara en internet (al menos no la he encontrado y he buscado), por eso escribo esta respuesta y espero que le sea útil a alguien. Algunas causas de un proyecto de React en blanco pueden ser:

1- Estás intentado ejecutar tu proyecto de React abriéndolo desde el explorador de archivos, esto es imposible, la solución es ejecutarlo en un servidor local o real.
2- Tu proyecto está en un subdirectorio, estás usando React Router y no has cambiado el basename.
Por defecto, react router funciona así:
<BrowserRouter >
   <App></App>
</BrowserRouter>

Pero esto solo funciona si lo ejecutas desde el directorio raíz de tu proyecto, para que funcione en un subdirectorio como: www/miProyecto, debes agregarle el basename a BrowserRouter, quedaría así:
<BrowserRouter basename="/miProyecto/index.html">
      <App></App>
</BrowserRouter>

Cabe destacar que es importante agregar index.html al final para que funcione.
3- El build de tu app de React importa los archivos generados con / en vez de ./ para solucionar esto, tu archivo de configuración de vite.config.js debe estar así:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: './',
})

Aquí la clave es base: './' Además, ten en cuenta que si importaste un fichero de javascript al index.html de React deberás agregarlo en la carpeta dist con la misma ruta o modificar la ruta del dist para que coincida con la ubicación del fichero.
Creo que estos puntos son algo que React, React Router y Vite deben solucionar
